# Can't uninstall Android Studio

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, windows-10, uninstallation

I'm having problems uninstalling Android Studio in Win10, I can't find the uninstall.exe file. I installed it, but I'm not going to use it, after all, so I went to Control Panel>Programs and Features, but when I tried from there it said it couldn't find the uninstall.exe and removed it from the list, I have the Android Studio folders in Program Files and all, but that's it.

I already removed the SDK from the user folder. All that's left is in Program Files. I tried reinstalling but only creates another installation folder under 'Android Studio1'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you located uninstall.exe in your AS folder?

Comment: I looked in the AS folder but couldn't find the uninstall.exe file.

Comment: Go to C:\Users\%username%, and delete .android, .AndroidStudio(#version-number), .gradle and AndroidStudioProjects directories if they exist. After that go to C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming and delete the JetBrains directory. Then you are fine.

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your assistance, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment by [Flot2011](http://A%20comment%20by%20Flot2011%20answered%20this%20question.%20%20Flot2011%27s%20comment:%20*Go%20to%20C:%5CUsers%5C%25username%25,%20and%20delete%20.android,%20.AndroidStudio(#version-number),%20.gradle%20and%20AndroidStudioProjects%20directories%20if%20they%20exist.%20After%20that%20go%20to%20C:%5CUsers%5C%25username%25%5CAppData%5CRoaming%20and%20delete%20the%20JetBrains%20directory.*%20%20Just%20follow%20Flot2011%27s%20directions%20and%20restart%20your%20PC,%20and%20Android%20Studio%20is%20no%20more%20on%20your%20computer.) answered this question.

Flot2011's comment:

> Go to C:\Users%username%, and delete .android,
> .AndroidStudio(#version-number), .gradle and AndroidStudioProjects
> directories if they exist. After that go to
> C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming and delete the JetBrains
> directory.

Just follow Flot2011's directions and restart your PC, and Android Studio is no more on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to resolve this exact issue:

1. Launch Android Studio.
2. Upgrade Android Studio to the latest version when prompted.
3. Delete C:\Program Files\Android\
4. [Download the latest Android Studio installer.](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads)
5. Install the latest Android Studio. This will replace the files removed in step 3, and install a functioning uninstaller.
6. Run the uninstaller from the Settings app. Make sure to check the user preferences box so that it deletes the files in %userprofile%.

I prefer this approach to manually removing directories because the installers and updaters should get all of them and also address any registry changes that need to be made.